# log4j2 config file not logging to console/file

Tags: log4j2, log4j

I have the following log4j2.xml config that I am using. 
I have 2 issues :-

1. When my application runs up, I have nothing logged to either the
   console or to mylog.log file by either of apache or springframework or
   hibernate classes.
2. Classes within the package "com.foo.bar", I am able change the log
   LEVEL via "level" attribute but the messages are only logged to
   mylog.log file but nothing to the console

Any suggestions to above would be appreciated ?

thank you
Pete

```
<Appenders>

    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="File" fileName="mylog.log"
        filePattern="mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="30 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <Logger name="com.foo.bar" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.apache" level="debug" >
        <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="File" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="File" />
    </Logger>       

    <Root level="all">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="File" />
    </Root>

</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing

```
<Root level="all">
```

With

```
<Root level="trace">
```

Comment: Hi Remko

Tried the suggestion, unfortunately, did not make any change.

Thank you for the suggestion.
Pete

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a misconfigured log.

Can you debug remotely and where you find use the logger to log something place a breakpoint.  Inspect the logger and then you will find a location of where its picking up the log file from.

Also try providing a VM argument for log4j configuration (-Dlog4j.configuration)on start-up of your application.